# Show two AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

How can do I show an `AlertDialog` when showing another.

more:
I have an `AlertDialog` named for easy refrence `DeviceDialog`
another one is `ExitDialog`

I call show on `ExitDialog` when `DeviceDialog` is showing
after that, automatically `DeviceDialog` hides or dismissed or cancled (I don't know which)

How can do I prevent that or reShow `DeviceDialog` after `ExitDialog` hides

Comment: Pretty sure you can't show more than on dialog at a time. You should create a more generic dialog, and then switch the view inside of it if you need it to show something different.

Comment: I test two simple Dialogs (not AlertDialog) and I can have multi opened Dialog in the activity. but I can't do that for AlertDialogs

Answer (score 1):

I solve that

basicly when you call setButton the button first dismiss/cancel dialog and then call your code

simply I add

```
alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_<POSITIVE/NEGATIVE/..>).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ...
});
```

for each button I want in
    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        ...
    });
after I create the dialog

Now the dialog doesn't hide(dismiss/..) after click buttons
So I can show new AlertDialogs on this AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

Don't show ExitDialog if DeviceDialog is showing

```
if (!DeviceDialog.isShowing())
{
    ExitDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: AlertDialog are modal dialogs, it's not possible to show both at the same time

Comment: It's necessary for my app to prevent DeviceDialog to closed automatically because it controls my app data security

Comment: How can do I change a simple Dialog to Have AlertDialog|ProgressDialog Buttons (I just use AlertDialogs because of theme to create normal dialogs for my apps)

Comment: Maybe this will prevent the dialog dismissal DeviceDialog.setCancelable(false);

Comment: I set that. If AlertDialogs are modal no code can stop this action. How can do I add normal (official!) Buttons for simple Dialogs

Comment: I guess you will have to write your own custom Dialog indeed. This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android